# c extern при множественном объявлении

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите, как ведет себя **extern** в следующей ситуации:

```
extern int a,
           b,
           c;
```

Все три переменные **a**, **b** и **c** являются внешними, так ведь?

Comment: Да. Но лучше так не делать.

Comment: Более задумчивая ситуация с декларацией функции с флагом `extern` :)

Comment: Почему так лучше не делать?

Comment: Кто минусует вопрос, может быть вы лучше поможете разобраться или хотя бы объясните, что не так?

Comment: Мало поддаётся анализу, разнесено по коду, значение может присваиваться в разных местах, плохо поддается контролю.. итд Вот по этим причинам лучше так не делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, все 3 являются внешними.

Кстати, чтобы это проверить, достаточно их объявить и использовать с наблюдаемым поведением (это важно!). В таком случае линкер сообщит о попытках использовать несуществующие переменные: https://ideone.com/rgf40P

```
extern int a, b, c;

int main()
{
  return a + b + c;
}
```

```
/home/CPCz1j/ccrst43X.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2): undefined reference to `b'
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8): undefined reference to `a'
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe): undefined reference to `c'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, что значит "с сайд-эффектами".

Comment: @AnT, имеется в виду, что обращения должны остаться в скомпилированном коде. Если побочных эффектов нет, то оптимизатор может просто убрать обращения и ошибок не будет: https://ideone.com/kN0ic1. Соответственно в качестве побочных эффектов могут быть вывод или, как в моём примере, возврат из main.

Comment: ОК. Но это формально называется "наблюдаемое поведение". "Побочные эффекты" - это несколько другое.

Comment: @AnT, запомню, исправил.

Answer (score 2):

В синтаксисе объявления спецификатор класса хранения `extern` входит в "общую" часть объявления (*declaration-specifiers* в С, *decl-specifier-seq* в С++), то есть относится ко всем деклараторам в объявлении, а не к какому-то одному. В вашем примере все три переменные объявлены с внешним связыванием.

Отдельный вопрос - что вы имеете в виду под "являются внешними". Спецификатор `extern` просто придает идентификатору *внешнее связывание*. Но он совсем не говорит, что данная переменная *определена* где-то в другом месте.

Например, объявление

```
extern int a,
           b = 42,
           c;
```

говорит о том, что переменные `a` и `c` имеют внешнее связывание и определены где-то в другом месте, а вот переменная `b` имеет внешнее связывание и определена здесь (и доступна из других мест).

Другими словами, спецификатор `extern` может иметь как семантику "импорта", так и семантику "экспорта", в зависимости от того, является ли *объявление* переменной или функции еще и *определением*.

Comment: Ну так ведь проблема не в том, что **extern** используется при множественном объявлении, а в том, что при множественном объявлении с использованием **extern** одна из переменных определяется. Есть ведь устоявшиеся подходы организации объявлений/определений, когда внешняя переменная определяется в *.c файле как **int var**, а объявляется в *.h файле как **extern int var**. Какой смысл использовать **extern** в *.c файле? Без интерфейсного *.h файла такая переменная все равно не будет доступна нигде, кроме данного *.c файла, только путаница возникает.

Comment: Например, **MinGW** в случае **extern int var = 3** вполне обоснованно кидает в лицо предупреждение.

Comment: В С использовать `extern` с *определениями* переменных смысла нет, потому что и без него переменная, определенная на уровне файла, имеет внешнее связывание по умолчанию. А вот в С++ такой смысл вполне может быть: в С++ const-объекты имеют *внутреннее* связывание по умолчанию. Явный `extern` в определении там вполне может понадобиться. Предупреждение, которое кидает MinGW - необоснованное. Точнее, оно рассчитано уж совсем на чайников.

Comment: Что касается вашего "ведь проблема в том..." - я не понимаю, о какой "проблеме" вы говорите. Никакой проблемы тут нет. Я, разумеется, не призываю никого смешивать объявления с определениями в одном мульти-объявлении.

Comment: Возможно, я виноват в том, что решил обобщить свой вопрос, указав в заголовке **c/c++**, вместо **c**. Я большую часть времени пишу на **c**, поэтому автоматически подразумеваю поведение для **c**, а не для **c++**.

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь, но на сколько я помню, Стивен Прата говорил в своей книге, что в **C** функции по умолчанию имеют внешнее связывание, а переменные - внутреннее, то есть **static**

Comment: @Максим: Это было бы странно. В С всё по умолчанию имеет *внешнее* связывание. И переменные (уровня файла), и функции.

Comment: Все верно, я просто что-то напутал.